# Python Scripting : how to execute unix commands inside gdb prompt using python script..?

Tags: python, gdb

I want to execute linux commands (eg. bt, break, frame etc) inside gdb prompt using python scripting.
for example: i am using    `subprocess.call(["gdb"], shell=True)`
this line takes me to (gdb) prompt by executing  gdb command but after it when i try
    `subprocess.call(["backtrace"], shell=True)`
it shows /bin/sh:backtrace: command not found

Answer (score 2):

`backtrace` isn't a linux command, it's a `gdb` command.

If you want to send commands to a popen'd gdb session, you have to push them through `stdin`, with something like...

```
import subprocess

gdb = subprocess.Popen(['gdb'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
gdb.stdin.write('backtrace\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

The commands you type into a `(gdb)` prompt like **backtrace**, **break**, **frame** etc are gdb commands. Only gdb knows how to interpret them and they won't work with `subprocess.call()` as the latter can only run Linux executable files.

There are two ways to accomplish something close to what you want:

1. Start GDB under the control of Python and use the [GDB/MI](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html#GDB_002fMI) protocol to talk to it. This is how [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/) works. E.g. `p = subprocess.Popen(['gdb', '-i=mi'], stdin=fd_in, stdout=fd_out)`. See also https://bitbucket.org/minami/python-gdb-mi/src/tip/gdbmi/session.py?at=default
2. Use GDB's builtin Python scripting. ([API Reference](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html)) E.g.

Save this to **t.py**

```
import gdb

gdb.execute('set confirm off')
gdb.execute('file /bin/true')
gdb.execute('start')
gdb.execute('backtrace')
gdb.execute('quit')
```

Then run:

```
$ gdb -q -x t.py
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4014c0: file true.c, line 59.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde28) at true.c:59
59    if (argc == 2)
#0  main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde28) at true.c:59
$
```